# MySQL JDBC connection stop working

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
String user = "root";
String pass = "root1";

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    System.out.println("Connected to database");
} catch (Exception e) {         
    System.out.println(e);
    System.out.println("Could not connect to database");
}
```

Password should be "root". The program does not display the message in the catch block and stops working. Can anyone tell me what happens?

[UPDATE]
I apologise I asked a bad question. The problem is already solved, Thanks. This helps to properly check whether the connection exists.

```
if (conn1 != null) {
    System.out.println("Connected to the database test1");
}
```

Comment: try to print stackTrace in catch block as `e.printStackTrace()`, also paste that error here.

Comment: It doesn't show anything in the console, just stop there. It doesn't enter the catch block.

Comment: try commenting this line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` and re run. let see...

Comment: try using debugger

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are three different ways to connect to  SQL data base as shown in below code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MySQLConnectExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // creates three different Connection objects
        Connection conn1 = null;
        Connection conn2 = null;
        Connection conn3 = null;

        try {
            // connect way #1
            String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "secret";

            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
            if (conn1 != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test1");
            }

            // connect way #2
            String url2 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test2?user=root&password=secret";
            conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url2);
            if (conn2 != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test2");
            }

            // connect way #3
            String url3 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test3";
            Properties info = new Properties();
            info.put("user", "root");
            info.put("password", "secret");

            conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(url3, info);
            if (conn3 != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test3");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred. Maybe user/password is invalid");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: The check whether the connection exists helps. if (conn1 != null) { System.out.println("Connected to the database test1"); }